# Database error when call Content in other fragment

Tags: javascript, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
 public import_fragment.Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_IMAGEURI }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    import_fragment.Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}
```

When i try to change 'Contact' to import_fragment.Contact i get error in this line:`new import_fragment.Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));`

error say `com.al3almya.users.al3almya.import_fragment is not an en closing class`

Also i get this error in this line too

```
public List<import_fragment.Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<import_fragment.Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<import_fragment.Contact>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contacts.add(new import_fragment.Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5))));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

When i change Contact to import_fragment.Contact i get error in this line `contacts.add(new import_fragment.Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5))));`

Error says `com.al3almya.users.al3almya.import_fragment is not an en closing class`